# Why is the intercept of linear regression biased?

Tags: r, regression, least-squares, monte-carlo, estimators

Out of curiosity, I conducted the following simulation (code below). Why is it that when the variance of the error term is large coefficient associated with the intercept is biased? Can you recommend some reference that discusses this? Or better yet is there a formal proof of that?

```
rm(list=ls())
set.seed(12345)
m  <- 10000
x1 <- runif(m,0,100)       # random numbers from uniform distribution
x2 <- 1:10000
u  <- rnorm(m,0,100)       # random numbers from standard normal distribution
y  <- 5*x1 + 2*x2 + 10 + u # generating y series
data  <- cbind(x1, x2, y)
beta1 <- c()
beta2 <- c()
beta3 <- c()
R2    <- c()
n       <- 1000 # number of loops
ksubset <- 100  # length of subset
for (i in 1:n){
  datam <- data.frame(data[sample(nrow(data),ksubset), ])
  ols   <- summary(lm(y~x1+x2, data=datam))
  beta1 <- append(beta1, ols$coefficients[1])
  beta2 <- append(beta2, ols$coefficients[2])
  beta3 <- append(beta3, ols$coefficients[3])
  R2    <- append(R2,    ols$r.squared)
}

results <- c(mean(beta1), mean(beta2), mean(beta3))
results
## [1] 7.290909 5.027431 2.000345
```

The code takes thousand random samples of size 100 from the population and calculates a regression in each. Then I take the average of each of the estimated coefficients, which in theory should be equal to the original model. It works great for the slopes, but not for the intercept.

**Update**

I have noticed that with the population set at 10,000, the bias persists. If I increase the size of the population to 1,000,000, the bias disappears. The size of the target population was insufficient. Anyway, @Maarten's answer is a step in the right direction.

**Update2**

Entire population results:

```
> summary(lm(y~x1+x2))       
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-367.24  -66.37   -0.33   66.64  385.26 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 7.0388165  2.6626801    2.644  0.00822 ** 
x1          5.0296554  0.0348480  144.331  < 2e-16 ***
x2          2.0002959  0.0003465 5772.764  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 100 on 9997 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9997,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.9997 
F-statistic: 1.667e+07 on 2 and 9997 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I updated the question, including simulation results (result). I also present the model results with the entire population, which in effect is biased due to the huge variance. The simulation, as expected, reproduce those results correctly. I repeat, my mistake is in the size of the target population.

Comment: Could you add an (non-code) explanation about what the experiment does, and show the results?

Comment: There are some obvious problems in the code. For instance, `x2` is not a vector of length `100`, which it ought to be.  As is well known and mathematically demonstrated, the coefficients are *not* biased.  We have to conclude that you are asking us to debug this code.

Comment: x2 need not be of length 100, because the population there are 10,000 elements. I do not see the programming error. The simulation is a fundamental part of the statistics, I do not see why the question is off-topic. If the error was programming, the program does not work and it does.  Maybe the problem is elsewhere. In fact, if I reduce the variance to a smaller value, the bias disappears.

Comment: When I independently code the same (intended) simulation I cannot reproduce what you describe.  Because your question relies entirely on the code, it evidently is purely a coding question.  If you could express your question using a more general language, such as English and mathematics, we might be able to identify a statistical issue we could help you with.

Comment: My answer did not suggest that you increase the size of your population, but that you increase the number of samples you draw from that population.

Comment: As noted in my comment below, try changing the random seed a few times. You'll see your estimate of the intercept bounce right around 10. Your example just happens to be "statistical significant" by chance...but I'm using quotes there because you forgot to account to the fact that the way you analyzed the data does *not* account for the fact that your MC samples are not independent (so your pvalue is not valid).

Comment: Certainly, the numbers are pseudorandom. But because you say they are not independent?

Comment: You first make one big data set and then randomly sample from that data set. Because the same observation can appear in multiple samples, the samples are not independent.

Comment: Underneath the coding issues, there are statistical misunderstandings here that we can clear up. IMO, this should stay open.

Comment: @CliffAB Sampling with replacement from a larger population does not mean that the samples aren't independent. Not independent means that the chance of sampling one unit changes when one sampled another unit. This is not the case with sampling with replacement. In fact, what Héctor does is very much in line with what the bootstrap does.

Comment: @gung I share your suspicion that there is a topical question here.  However, the question *as currently stated* and *as answered* (for which I give a hearty +1) is `R`-centric and appears to stem from a bug in the code.  Pending the hoped-for (and requested) edits to the question, I have re-closed it.

Comment: @MaartenBuis: sampling with replacement provides independent samples *from your original sample*, which are then dependent samples *from the population of interest*. What I think is confusing is that I was referring to the mistake of computing a t-statistic from `mean(beta1 - 10) / (sd(beta1) / sqrt(n) )` (`n` is number of loops from code). You can see this is immediately flawed: fixing the original sample size (m), you can let n->infinity and your t-statistic is unbounded.

Comment: Hector: the results are not biased, there is just random error. The true value of the intercept is 10. Your results show that the estimate of intercept is 7, with standard error 2.6. This result is consistent with the true mean of the estimated intercept being 10.

Comment: @CliffAB Absolutely agree. It's the answer I was expecting, I had left that detail aside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The role of the constant is to force the mean of the errors to be 0. In your program the mean of the error term is 0 in your population, but the variance is very high, so it will deviate a lot from 0 in many of your samples. This means that in each sample the constant can deviate a lot from the population value. So much so that a 1000 replications is not enough to find that on average you will get the right constant. Try and increase the number of replications to say 10,000 or 100,000 and see what happens.

---

**Update**

As promised I tried to replicate Héctor's results, but I gues I did something wrong the first time I tried, as I can't reproduce it anymore. Maybe I set the residual standard deviation at 1000 instead of 100, maybe I tried 100 replications instead of a 1000, or some silly typo like that. Anyhow here is my simulation with a 1000 replications in Stata, and a constant that is close enough to 10 given the spread.

```
. set seed 123456

. clear all

. program define sim
  1.         drop _all
  2.         set obs 100
  3.         gen x1 = runiform() < .5
  4.         gen x2 = rnormal()
  5.         gen y  = 5*x1 + 2*x2 + 10 + rnormal(0,100)
  6.         reg y x1 x2
  7. end

. simulate b=_b[_cons], reps(1000) nodots : sim

      command:  sim
            b:  _b[_cons]


. sum

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
           b |      1,000     9.94305    14.99877  -46.69164   60.36443
```

Comment: $1000$ replications is more than enough replications for these parameters; a correct simulation will produce a nearly Normally distributed set of estimates of the intercept that is squarely centered on the specified value of $10$.

Comment: @whuber I did a quick simulation myself and could replicate Hector's "results". The key was the huge residual variance. I will update the answer tomorrow with that simulation.

Comment: Thank you, Maarten.  Since you could replicate the results, I will vote to reopen the thread--but in the meantime I hope the OP will find a way to communicate the problem more clearly.

Comment: @whuber: one simple "simulation" is to just change the random seed a few times. Doing so will show the intercept bouncing around 10.

Comment: @Cliff And that's exactly what an unbiased estimator of $10$ is supposed to do.

Comment: @whuber: exactly. I was just offering a very easy way of informally showing this given the current code.

Comment: @MaartenBuis, you define your covariates differently, although it should not affect the outcome at all. You code (without being very studious of Stata) it is correct. But I do not know if the seeds are the same in both statistical packages.

Comment: They are in all likelihood different. I tried different seeds to see if I could replicate your results, but to no effect. So I don't think the solution is there.